# Fluent NHibernate unit testing

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to write some persistence tests and verify mappings against a database, my issue is (and I may be fundamentally misunderstanding something here)

Pre-conditions

1. The database is created manually and is in a state of flux
2. The mappings need to be updated when column names are changed, added or deleted
3. I dont want to affect the database itself during testing

Ideally I'd like to take the current database schema (SQL 2008) and replicate it in memory, so I can carry out my unit tests safe in the knowledge that when I finish my tests the SQL database will be intact and unchanged.

I've looked at using SQLite In Memory but if I understand things correctly it will generate the schema based on the mapping files rather than check the mappings are valid against the database itself, so how would I replicate my SQL 2008 database schema into SQLite without much effort? Or should I go down the route of building a new SQL 2008 Database at the start of my tests and deconstruct it at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with an in-memory copy rather than a real DB will prove different things about your implementation.

- With an in-memory copy you will have faster integration tests that will prove that your logic will work fine with an in memory representation. Maybe It's just fine for mapping purposes.
- With a real DB you'll have slower integration tests, which can give you an estimate of the performance and you'll prove that your logic works just fine with the real thing. Obviously you'll need an ad hoc Test DB to setup and revert before and after each test/fixture.

In my experience I found the second approach giving more value in integration tests while using the first approach through mocks and stubs for unit tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that I need to rebuild my database as part of my build script, its the only way I'll be able to ensure mappings and databases match each and every time.